# Why didn't the Google AdSense team approve my website (I followed all the requirements)?

Tags: google-adsense

I submitted my website to the Google AdSense team two months ago, but my site still is under review. I tried to do all the things they require.

This is my website: `http://pondicherryevents.com`  If I forgot to fulfill any of Google's AdSense requirements, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has a [form that you can fill out to check on your application status](https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/approvalstatus?hl=en&rd=1)

Here is a [FAQ about how long it will take to get approved](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/76228?hl=en)

> We can tell you how long our part of the approval process will take. However, some parts require actions on your end, and we can only continue the review after you complete them. You can see how the approval process works [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10162).
>
> **We have found that in most cases when publishers waited for a long time to be reviewed, it was because they have not implemented the ad code on an active page yet.**
>
> 1. Once you submitted your application, you will receive an email from us within 6 to 8 hours that will tell you whether you have passed the first step of the review process. If you passed the first check, you can then log in to your AdSense account. You will see a [red bar](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2708535) across the top of your account. To initiate the second step of the review, you need to [implement the ad code](http://www.google.com/adsense/v3/app?ghstartflowid=1335072#myads-viewall-adunits/product=SELF_SERVICE_CONTENT_ADS&view=ADUNITS&sourceid=GreylistingHCArticle&subid=AdUnitCreationGHF_GreylistingHCArticle&medium=GHF) on a page of your signup URL that receives traffic. If you do not implement the ad code, the review process will not continue.
> 2. Once our system detects that the code has been placed on a live page, we will automatically review your websites with the ad code - not only the page that you submitted in the application. It typically takes 2-3 days for our specialists to complete the review. Depending on the volume of applications we receive, it may sometimes take longer. As soon as we’ve reviewed your application, we’ll send you an email with details on your application status. If you implemented the ad code and it takes longer, make sure your code is implemented correctly and is placed on a page that receives impressions. Don’t place the code on a test page that has nothing but the ad code on it.
> 3. Once your application is fully approved, the ads automatically start showing in your AdSense for Content ad units and the red alert in your account disappears.